# Meteor for each on template?

Tags: javascript, meteor

In jQuery I have the following:

```
var dis = $('.dis').children();
for (var i = 0; i <= dis.length; i++){
$(dis.find('.somediv')[i]).text(funk.list[i].api.response);}
```

I am trying to change the formatting of my code to be reactive with Meteor. To that end, I am trying to convert my code like so:

```
this.mete = new ReactiveVar();
var self = this;
self.mete[i].set('funk.list[i].api.response');
```

The gist of all of this is that, in my jQuery code, I have a for-each loop that needs to be reflected in the `[i]` tags surrounding each div.

My HTML is something like so:

`<div class="dis"><div class="somediv"></div></div>
 <div class="dis"><div class="somediv"></div></div>`

The `self.mete[i].set` does not accomplish this. I would like to know how to go about this. Also, I understand that, in Meteor, the HTML would look something more like:

```
<div class="dis">{{mete}}</div>
<div class="dis">{{mete}}</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want something like this:

```
Template.mytemplate.onCreated(function(){
    this.mete = new ReactiveVar();
    var self = this;
    self.mete.set(YourListHere); //assuming your list is an array of object like {api: {response: "some response"}} 
});
Template.mytemplate.helper({
   "myList": function() {
      return Template.instance().mete.get();
   }
});
```

and in the template:

```
{{#each myList}}
<div class="dis">{{this.api.response}}</div>
{{/each}}
```

Comment: Only thing is that my list comes from jSON data, where I have to assign values `eg doing[0].it`. I am unclear exactly on how to go about setting a for loop on this. Using `{{#each}}` does not help me select the `[i]` value in a getJSON call I don't think.

Comment: Can you share an example of the data and the result you expect? Your data is an array; The `#each` loop loops through the array and within the `{{#each}}` template you get each item with `this`. So you can get all the keys of each element and use them using `{{this.key_to_use}}`. Not sure to understand what else you need.